# state variable are updating eachother in react redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-reducers

I am having trouble with react redux. In one of my reducer whose function is to add to cart.
I get the selected item as an object from array(e.g recentProducts). In array i change quantity unfortunately quantity also auto changes in the selected item object too. If i change the object the array holding the object changes too in same execution. I am not sure why this is happening. My store implementation is below.

```
     import { useMemo } from 'react';
        import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
        import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
        import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
        import {
            products,
            productsCollectionSix,
            productsCollectionSeven,
            productsCollectionEight,
            productsCollectionNine,
            productsCollectionTen,
            productsCollectionEleven,
            productsCovid19,
            productsGrocery,
            productsElectronics,
            productsFurniture
        } from '../json-data/products';
        
        let store
        
        import {
            ADD_TO_CART,
            REMOVE_ITEM,
            SUB_QUANTITY,
            ADD_QUANTITY,
            ADD_SHIPPING,
            ADD_QUANTITY_WITH_NUMBER,
            RESET_CART,
            ADD_TO_COMPARE,
            REMOVE_ITEM_FROM_COMPARE,
            UPDATE_RECENT_PRODUCTS,
            TOGGLE_LOGIN_STATE
        } from '../actions/action-types/action-names'
        
        const initialState = {
            products: products,
            productsCollectionSix: productsCollectionSix,
            productsCollectionSeven: productsCollectionSeven,
            productsCollectionEight: productsCollectionEight,
            productsCollectionNine: productsCollectionNine,
            productsCollectionTen: productsCollectionTen,
            productsCollectionEleven: productsCollectionEleven,
            productsCovid19: productsCovid19,
            productsGrocery: productsGrocery,
            productsElectronics: productsElectronics,
            productsFurniture: productsFurniture,
            recentProducts: [],
            addedItems: [],
            addedItemsToCompare: [],
            total: 0,
            shipping: 0,
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
        
        const reducers = (state = initialState, action) => {
     
        //My add to cart function
            if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
               //the selected item goes in itemToBeAdded
                let itemToBeAdded = state.products.find((item) => {
                    if (item._id === action._id) {
                        item["array"] = "products";
                        return item;
                    }
                })
                    || state.productsCollectionSix.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionSix";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCollectionSeven.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionSeven";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCollectionEight.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionEight";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCollectionNine.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionNine";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCollectionTen.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionTen";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCollectionEleven.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCollectionEleven";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsCovid19.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsCovid19";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsGrocery.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsGrocery";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsElectronics.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsElectronics";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.productsFurniture.find((item) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "productsFurniture";
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                    || state.recentProducts.find((item, index) => {
                        if (item._id === action._id) {
                            item["array"] = "recentProducts";
                            item["index"] = index;
                            return item;
                        }
                    })
                let modifiedRecentProducts = [...state.recentProducts];
    
               
                
                    switch (itemToBeAdded["array"]) {
                        case "recentProducts":
        
        
                            if ((parseFloat(modifiedRecentProducts[itemToBeAdded["index"]].quantity.$numberDecimal) - 1) >= 0) {
                                
                                //This is where i see things getting out of hands 
//itemToBeAdded updates item in array and if modifiedRecentProducts item is updated first it updates itemToBeAdded quantity too. 
modifiedRecentProducts[itemToBeAdded["index"]].quantity.$numberDecimal = parseFloat(modifiedRecentProducts[itemToBeAdded["index"]].quantity.$numberDecimal) - 1;
                                itemToBeAdded.quantity.$numberDecimal = 1;
                                
                                return {
                                    ...state,
                                    recentProducts: [...modifiedRecentProducts],
                                    addedItems: [...state.addedItems, itemToBeAdded],
                                    total: state.total + parseFloat(itemToBeAdded.salePrize.$numberDecimal)
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                    }
            }
            else {
                return state
            }
        }
        
        const initStore = (preloadedState = initialState) => {
            return createStore(
                reducers,
                preloadedState,
                composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))
            )
        }
        
        export const initializeStore = (preloadedState) => {
            let _store = store ?? initStore(preloadedState)
        
            // After navigating to a page with an initial Redux state, merge that state
            // with the current state in the store, and create a new store
            if (preloadedState && store) {
                _store = initStore({
                    ...store.getState(),
                    ...preloadedState,
                })
                // Reset the current store
                store = undefined
            }
        
            // For SSG and SSR always create a new store
            if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _store
            // Create the store once in the client
            if (!store) store = _store
        
            return _store
        }
        
        export const useStore = (initialState) => {
            const store = useMemo(() => initializeStore(initialState), [initialState])
            return store
        }
```

Comment: You have many places in the code where you are mutating objects. This is now how redux should work. You should always create a cloned object if your state, modify it, and return it in the end.

Comment: Can you explain what you are saying in detail. I am new to redux and i am working on this project but i didn't set it up that's why i am unable to figure it out.

Comment: [https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/redux-never-mutate-state/203091]
Objects in javascript are being passed by reference, and when you are doing item["array"] = "productsFurniture", you are changing the state. This can cause unexpected behaviour and should always be avoided. After you'll fix all these issues I would be happy to help you find the issue.